# Error when creating a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, create-table

I create a table named xyzcodes. It is a constraint for the other table, Industry. When I run the create script for Industry, I get the following error.

```
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'XYZCODES' 
that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 
'FK_INDUSTRY_XYZCODES'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Here is the create script in its entirety (some fields have been anonymized)

```
CREATE TABLE industry
(
state char(2) NOT NULL,
areatype char(2) NOT NULL,
area char(6) NOT NULL,
periodyear char(4) NOT NULL,
periodtype char(2) NOT NULL,
period char(2) NOT NULL,
codty char(2) NOT NULL,
code char(6) NOT NULL,
ownership char(2) NOT NULL,
prelim char(1) NULL,
firms numeric(8) NULL,
estab numeric(8) NULL,
avg numeric(9) NULL,
m1 numeric(9) NULL,
m2 numeric(9) NULL,
m3 numeric(9) NULL,
topempav numeric(9) NULL,
total numeric(14) NULL,
avgw numeric(8) NULL,
available numeric(14) NULL,
contrib numeric(12) NULL,
suppress char(1) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_INDUSTRY PRIMARY KEY (state,areatype,area,periodyear,periodtype,period,codty,code,ownership),
CONSTRAINT FK_INDUSTRY_GEOG FOREIGN KEY (state,areatype,area) REFERENCES geog(state,areatype,area),
CONSTRAINT FK_INDUSTRY_PERIOD FOREIGN KEY (periodyear,periodtype,period) 
REFERENCES period(periodyear,periodtype,period),
CONSTRAINT FK_INDUSTRY_INDCODES FOREIGN KEY (state,codty,code) 
REFERENCES indcodes(state,codetype,code),
CONSTRAINT FK_INDUSTRY_OWNERSHP FOREIGN KEY (state,ownership) REFERENCES ownershp(state,ownership),
```

);

Here is the layout for the xyzcode. This is created using the import and export wizard.

```
   state   char(4)  primary key (PK)
   codetype   char(2)   (PK)
   code       char(6)   (PK)
   codetitle  varchar(115)
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error. The XYZCODES table imported fine and contains the fields listed in the constraint.

Comment: try: CONSTRAINT FK_INDUSTRY_XYZCODES FOREIGN KEY (state,codetype,code)

Answer (score 0):

```
REFERENCES xyzcodes(stfips,codetype,code)
```

I don't see a `stfips` column in your xyzcodes definition:

```
   state   char(4)  primary key (PK)
   codetype   char(2)   (PK)
   code       char(6)   (PK)
   codetitle  varchar(115)
```

Comment: I made an edit. Trying to anonymize the data. I work for a government entity.

Comment: My suspicion is your attempt to anonymize the data is masking the actual problem in your code.  SQL Server is telling you that you have attempted to create a FK to a PK that doesn't exist.   You say that it does exist, but we have to take your word for it.   Sorry, but I'm inclined to believe SQL Server.   If you can post a script that reproduces the error, we can probably find the mistake for you.

Comment: The complete script is in the question now.

Comment: You also need to include the CREATE TABLE script for the table that the FK is trying to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but problem solved. In the beginning, I would import xyzcodes using the Import and Export Wizard. If you would go to the Object Explorer prior to this, you would see no mention of xyzcodes. It would import fine. From there, i would create industry using a script. Needless to say, that did not work.

As an experiment, I deleted both and created both xyzcodes and industry from script in that order. It works. Previously I was importing the data for xyzcodes and creating the table at the same time. Apparently, that is not the best way to do this.